# Save filtered view not working

Tags: filter, sharepoint-views

I created an Item list with column headers imported from a table created in Excel. I notice that when i try to sort (Ascend/Descend, etc) the column says, "This column type cannot be sorted." Why is this happening to my list?
NOTE: I have customized each column. Some are multi choice columns, some a single lines of text, some are dates.

Another issue is that I want to create views that i will share with the various program offices who will be submitting files on a given due date. Sharepoint has allowed me to save a few once they were sorted (see screen shot), but not others (see screenshots). I've tried to save the view in both Chrome & Explorer. What's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the column type.  If a column type is multiple lines of text or multiple choices on a choice column, or from a lookup list, then it's not sortable.